# Having an issue with getting a gatsby project to work

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying to get a gatsby project to work on a new system but I'm having a problem running gatsby develop on it. It seems to be related to a npm package that I added (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-use-dark-mode) to the project. The terminal outputs.

```
ERROR
UNHANDLED REJECTION Unable to find plugin "gatsby-plugin-use-dark-mode". Perhaps you need to install its package?
Error: Unable to find plugin "gatsby-plugin-use-dark-mode". Perhaps you need to install its package?
load.js:109 resolvePlugin [gatsby-site]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/load.js:109:11
load.js:153 processPlugin [gatsby-site]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/load.js:153:20
load.js:172 config.plugins.forEach.plugin [gatsby-site]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/load.js:172:20
Array.forEach
load.js:171 module.exports [gatsby-site]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/load.js:171:20
index.js:55 module.exports [gatsby-site]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/load-plugins/index.js:55:19
index.js:167 module.exports [gatsby-site]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/index.js:167:34
```

Comment: Have you [installed](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) the plugin?

Comment: Have you tried `gatsby clean`? It might be cached. Have you tried deleting node_modules and installing the dependencies?